# FTP fileupload with progress

Tags: .net, ftp

I'm going to write an ftp client using .NET Framework. I want to upload files and show how many bytes (or kilobytes) were exactly uploaded. I've been looking the way of uploading file over ftp with monitoring the progress but all of them are using libraries.

Is there any way of uploading over ftp and observing the process using standard .NET features?
If yes, I would be grateful for code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) for that. Register for its [`UploadProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadprogresschanged.aspx) and `UploadFileCompleted` events and upload the file using `UploadFileAsync()`.

Comment: is it possible to have fully fledged functionality when working with ftp as with FtpWebRequest? I mean upload over secured connections, to different ports, etc?

Comment: Well, not fully fledged, just things that you can express in an URL. And you can certainly do that with port numbers. Not sure about other stuff.

Comment: is there a way to change the buffer size by using the webclient?